retrieve boot time using pyvmomi
Im trying to get bootTime by "runtime.bootTime" but Im receiving error:
An error occurred while fetching data: 'runtime.bootTime'
    vm_properties = [
    "name", 
    "config.hardware.numCPU", 
    "config.hardware.memoryMB", 
    "guest.guestState", 
    "config.guestFullName", 
    "guest.net",
    "runtime.bootTime" # This is not working
]

Full code:
`def fetch_data(mode,force=1):
if mode == 'all':
    fetch_data('live',force)
    fetch_data('test',force)
    fetch_data('dev',force)
    return

# Decide skip or refresh
if force == 0 and not is_date_outdated(mode):
    return

credentials = load_config(mode)
write_timestamp(get_config(f"{mode.upper()}_DATE"), datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
filename = get_config(f"{mode.upper()}_CSV")

si = SmartConnect(
    host=credentials['host'],
    user=credentials['user'],
    pwd=credentials['pwd'],
    sslContext=ssl._create_unverified_context()
)

# Define VM properties to fetch
vm_properties = [
    "name", 
    "config.hardware.numCPU", 
    "config.hardware.memoryMB", 
    "guest.guestState", 
    "config.guestFullName", 
    "guest.net",
    "runtime.bootTime"
]

view = pchelper.get_container_view(si, obj_type=[vim.VirtualMachine])
vm_data_list = pchelper.collect_properties(si, view_ref=view, obj_type=vim.VirtualMachine, path_set=vm_properties, include_mors=True)

# Process and filter the fetched data
data = []
for vm_data in vm_data_list:
    processed_data = {}
    processed_data['name'] = vm_data['name']
    ip_addresses = [ip for net in vm_data['guest.net'] for ip in net.ipAddress if net.ipAddress and ':' not in ip and not ip.endswith(('.0', '.1'))]
    processed_data['ip'] = ", ".join(ip_addresses)
    processed_data['cpu_cores'] = vm_data['config.hardware.numCPU']
    processed_data['memory_MB'] = vm_data['config.hardware.memoryMB']
    processed_data['os'] = vm_data['config.guestFullName']
    processed_data['state'] = vm_data['guest.guestState']
    processed_data['boottime'] = vm_data['runtime.bootTime']
    
    data.append(processed_data)

# Save to CSV
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

# Cleanup
Disconnect(si)`

Tried summary.runtime.bootTime:
An error occurred while fetching data: 'summary.runtime.bootTime'
I used this guide to retrieve information quicker. Can you also help me with getting more information as I continuously improve the tool?
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/vminfo_quick.py

I solved the problem. The above code will work. Some machines were returning null. I solved by:
vm_data.get('runtime.bootTime', None)

